# looking for a smart way to compare DCDC Converter IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, converter

I'm looking for a quick and easy way to compare DCDC boost Converter IC, to all or most manufacturers. Does anyone know tools, sheets or charts?

Comment: I often use the parametric searches at some the big distributors like Digi-Key. Keep the specifications wide at the beginning and narrow down depending on what's most important to me.

Comment: As stated, it depends on what's important to you. Start by doing a basic search, then read their datasheets. Sometimes you'll find deal breakers in IC's that make them unsuitable for your use...etc. I don't think there is a single easy way to compare.

Answer (score 4):

Learn to use the parametric searches of most of the main suppliers, such as Digikey, Farnell, Mouser, Newark, and the many others. Selecting components and researching options for your designs is an extremely important and often overlooked part of designing something.

You may start the process first by thinking about what kind of device you want, so in your case a "DCDC boost Converter" which you can find categories in most supplier websites for at least the DC-DC converter part, and then you should be able to search for the "boost" or sometimes "buck-boost" if they have multiple/selectable modes of operation.

Then think about if you want internal switches and low current handling capability (usually ~3A max for integrated ones) or if you want an external switch controller to handle 10's of Amps.

Be sure to find ICs with proper voltage ratings for what you are doing, and be aware that some may have annoying little options/hidden issues so always check the datasheets after finding something that you THINK at first look seems to fit the need you have.

Some ICs may have huge amounts of external circuitry required too, especially if they have lots of really cool options like built in current limiting, microncontroller feedback interfaces etc. whereas some are very simple and need only ~6-8 or less external components.

Many many hours can be taken up by looking for the right IC, and should be a very important part of your project. Do not think you can just whack any old IC whose part number you see thrown around on random forums.

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple global list somewhere.  Such ICs also have many different parameters, with the priorities varying among them across different applications.

The simplest thing to do is to go to a distributor, like Mouser or DigiKey, and start drilling down *by the parameters you care about*.  That only shows you what might fit among the manufacturers carried by that distributor.  No distributor carries all manufacturers, and sometimes the parameters they picked that you can filter on a awkward.  Watch out for things like one part being listed as 500 mA and another 0.5 A.  These may show up in very different places when sorted by current capability.

This process will yield candidates only.  You then have to read the datasheets carefully for candidate parts.  There are a lot of details, but they matter.

Usually for things like boost converter ICs, I'll go straight to a few likely manufacturer web sites.  After a while, you get to know what each one is good at.  For example, for lower voltages, like up to 20 V maybe I'd start with Microchip.  For good all around wide product line, TI.  For nice parts but at a premium, Linear Tech.  For good prices in production quantities, ST.  For really high volume when you can afford a lot of engineering and qualification time and have the resources and patients to establish a relationship with the manufacturer, there are some less well known far east manufacturers.  However, if you're asking here, they aren't for you.

Comment: Hi! I have found a great Tool for smart comparison: www.dcdcselector.com Thanks for your Answers as well!